# How to convert only one axis when constructing a dataframe from a JSON string?

Tags: python, json, pandas

The [read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) function has an argument `convert_axes`.

The problem is that for my data the column labels MUST NOT be converted (i.e. keep them as strings), but the index MUST be converted.

My dumb solution is to parse the string twice. Surely there is a better way?

```
json_str = '{"1": {"1970-01-02 00:00:00": "foo"}}'
temp = pd.read_json(json_str, convert_axes=False)
want = pd.read_json(json_str, convert_axes=True)
want.columns = temp.columns
```

`json_str` always comes in the format `{column -> {index -> value}}`, i.e. `orient='columns'`. The index does not have to be in datetime format, it could be an integer index, or something else.

Comment: Can you please share sample input and expected output?

Comment: Where's your input json?

Comment: @NYCCoder It's in the first line of the code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) and the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/89c5a5941c4819e00a04d3f3722f9f5c9cf046f0/pandas/io/json/_json.py), I don't think there is a way to apply `convert_axes` to just one axis.

I'm not sure this is any better than your own solution:

```
import pandas as pd
json_str = '{"1": {"1970-01-02 00:00:00": "foo"}}'
df = pd.read_json(json_str, convert_axes=False)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Edit: I misunderstood the question the first time. Here's another go, which as requested leaves the column labels as strings but tries to convert the index:

```
import pandas as pd

def read_json_convert_index(json_str,dtypes=['int','float']):
    '''
    Leaves the columns untouched but tries to convert the index to datetime
    and then subsequentially to the types provided in the list dtypes
    '''

    df = pd.read_json(json_str,convert_axes=False)

    try:
        df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
        return df
    except:
        for dtype in dtypes:
            try:
                df.index = df.index.astype(dtype)
                # check if floats are actually just integers in disguise
                if dtype == 'float' and all(
                    [abs(i - int(i)) <= 0.1**10 for i in df.index]):
                        df.index = df.index.astype('int')
                        return df
                else: return df
            except: continue
        return df
```

Subsequent edit: As far I can see from the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/89c5a5941c4819e00a04d3f3722f9f5c9cf046f0/pandas/io/json/_json.py) and from experimentation, `convert_axes` tries to cast each axis as either a timestamp, an integer or a float, although I may well have overlooked something. Incidentally, through this experimentation I found some potentially unexpected (unwanted?) behaviour: If you run this...

```
import pandas as pd
json_str = '{"1": {"1.0": "foo"},"2": {"2.0": "bar"}}'
df = pd.read_json(json_str, convert_axes=True)
```

... then the axis is converted to a DatetimeIndex `['1970-01-01 00:00:01', '1970-01-01 00:00:02']`. I think the reason for this is that the float `1.0` is interpreted as the timestamp `1970-01-01 00:00:01`. The function `read_json_convert_index` defined above does **not** do this, as it tries to cast the *string* `'1.0'` as a timestamp, which fails.

As for the condition `abs(i - int(i)) <= 0.1**10`: This checks whether the floats are very close to integer values and thus can be safely cast as integers. For instance, the code

```
import pandas as pd
json_str = '{"1": {"1.0": "foo"},"2": {"2.0": "bar"}}'
df = read_json_convert_index(json_str)
```

produces the index `[1, 2]`, rather than `[1.0, 2.0]`.

Just a general point: I think one should be wary with automatic type conversion, since it can lead to unexpected behaviour, as demonstrated above.

Comment: you are probably right that `convert_axes` probably does not accept for only one axis. But the OP said that the index can be something else than datetime. Maybe if you have a more general solution that would cast automatically the index to datetime or float or int depending on what is it, it would be a better answer :)

Comment: This does not work for me. As I said, the index does not have to be in datetime format, it could be an integer index, or something else. Only important thing is that pandas attempts to convert it.

Comment: @actual_panda I forgot the import alias. The code should work now.

Comment: Are datetime, `int` and `float` the only conversions `pandas` would attempt with `convert_axes=True`? What' the `abs(i - int(i))...` line for? Thanks.

Comment: It's indeed strange that `pandas` tries to convert non-date-like numbers (for which `pandas.to_datetime` would throw an error) to datetime before it tries integer- or float-conversion. I have written my own conversion with int -> float -> datetime precedence similar to your code. Thanks for the help!